# How to output the inverse of a list

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code and I would like to display it in the reversed order:

```
                <div id="gallery-1" class="royalSlider rsDefault visibleNearby">


            <?php
            $current_item = 1;
            $imgID = 1;

            foreach( $cats as $key => $item ){

            if( !empty($cat_id) && $cat_id == $item->id ){
                $current_item = $key+1;
            }?>

              <img class="rsImg" src="<?php echo cmMedia::getOriginalUrl($item->media_id);?>" id="imgID<?php echo $imgID; ?>" />
              <a class="rsImg" href="<?php echo cmMedia::getOriginalUrl($item->media_id);?>" id="imgID<?php echo $imgID; ?>" /></a>

            <?php $imgID++; }?>



            </div>
```

the output is a slider with 26 slides.

I tried flipping the + with - and starting the variables from 26 to 1 but it didn't work :/

Thx in advance!

Comment: Can you give me a $cats array print_r output?

Comment: `foreach` starts at the first element in a collection/list/array and loops until it is at the last element. If you use `for` instead of `foreach`, can you think of a way to start at the last element and then work your way back to the first element? (tip: you almost had it with flipping `+`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `array_reverse`?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

```
<?php
  $current_item = 1;
  $imgID = 1;
  $cats = array_reverse($cats);
  //... the rest should be the same as you have
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_reverse` is fine, another way to do it is switch out the `foreach` for an inverted `for` loop:

```
for ($key = count($cats) - 1; $key >= 0; $key--) {
    $item = $cats[$key];

    // Proceed with the original code
}
```